# ViewData.value empty in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewbag

I have index() action in my controller with

```
        ViewBag.somekey = "somevalue";
        MyModel m = new MyModel();
        return View(m);
```

and index.cshtml file with:

```
@Viewbag.somekey
@Html.Partial("_pv", model)
```

In index.cshtml, @ViewBag.somekey renders "somevalue", but in "_pv.cshtml" @ViewBag.somekey is blank. "_pv.cshtml" is shared partial view.

Can someone point me what to do here and how to get value of "somekey" in partial view?

Comment: Writing `@ViewBag.somekey` in a partial should just work fine. Something else is going in your code which breaks this. Make sure that you haven't misstyped `somekey` in your partial...

Comment: typing is ok, but i think it has to do something with _pv being shared partial view, and in different folder than index.cshtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well its simple, when ever you are rendering partial view , the ActionResult method which has a partial view must have a defination for ViewBag.somekey = "somevalue"; then only it can show the value for your ViewBag

example

if you want to render this partial view on other ActionResult View suppose

```
public ActionResult Index2()
{
ViewBag.somekey = "somevalue";
return View();
}
```

you have to define this ViewBag again